# Multer file buffer missing

Tags: node.js, multer

the req.file property returned from the following does not contain a buffer property (https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer). So when I try to access req.file.buffer it returns undefined. Can someone help to explain.
`

```
const multer = require('multer')
const uploadtest = multer({
    dest: 'avatar'
})

router.post('/uploadtest', uploadtest.single('upload'), (req, res)=>{
    console.log(req.file)
    req.user.avatar = req.file.buffer
    await req.user.save()
    
    res.send()
    }, (error, req, res, next)=>{ 
        res.status(400).send({error: error.message})
    }
)
```

`
the output from console.log(req.file) is:

```
{
  fieldname: 'upload',
  originalname: 'sample-doc-file.doc',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'application/msword',
  destination: 'avatar',
  filename: 'e488d6205717d45f397782b79d45fd8e',
  path: 'avatar\\e488d6205717d45f397782b79d45fd8e',
  size: 22528
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is expected, since you are using DiskStorage - the code initializes `multer` with a "dest" option, so it will save the files locally. Take a look at the multer README - the API doc says in the "Note" column that `buffer` is for MemoryStorage only.

Therefore, you must decide - do you wish to save the files to the filesystem (and get the path), or load into memory in full (and get the buffer)? In the latter case, the README contains a section called "MemoryStorage" that demonstrates how to configure multer:

```js
const storage = multer.memoryStorage()
const upload = multer({ storage: storage })
```

Comment: Their docs bit confusing should have this example of the snippet.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same issue, **req.file.buffer** was undefined. As Robert pointed out, I was using the **dest** option for **multer**. This is what worked for me:

```
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer();

router.post('/', upload.single('image_file'), myController)
```

then on myController

```
var buffer = req.file.buffer;
```

Answer (score 2):

New 2.0 no longer requires storage. Below worked for me

```
const multer = require('multer')
const upload = multer()

app.post('/upload', upload.single('audiofile'), async (req,res) => {
    const filename = `my ${x} upload `
    const bucketname = 'name-bucket'
    const file = req.file.buffer
    console.log('FILE', file)
    const link = await uploadAudio(filename, bucketname, file)
    console.log(link)
    res.send('uploaded successfully')
})
```

Output Code

```
  ETag: '"2c21f2b5d2893279acc3349e8a3881aa"',
  Location: 'https://name-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/my%20first%20upload',  
  key: 'my first upload',
  Key: 'my first upload',
  Bucket: 'name-bucket'
```

Was able to get location of file so I can download

Answer (score 1):

To get the benefit of `await` you must write `async` before `(req, res) => {}`

Answer (score 1):

If we **use** the `dest` option, multer stores the image in that directory.

But if we **do not use** it, then multer does not save the image in any directory. It just passes the data(`req.file`) through our function so we can do something with it.

So we have two options:

1. do not add the `dest` option as [Yaach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70779560/12991077) mentioned.
2. add `storage` option as [Robert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69922094/12991077) mentioned