# Buffer object in req.file is coming undefined in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, multer

Form in frontend React.js.

```
const handleUpload = (e) => {
    setFormvalue({ ...formvalue, recevierImages: e.target.files[0] });
  };

  const submitData = () => {
    console.log(formvalue);
    dispatch(createDonation(getFormData(formvalue)));
  };

   <Form>
     <Form.Item name="donationImage" label="Upload Image">
        <input type="file" onChange={(e) => handleUpload(e)} />
      </Form.Item>
   </Form>
   <Button onClick={submitData} type="primary">
      Create
    </Button>
```

recevierImages is the name were image is stored in react and on click of submitData all the data is appended to FormData and send to express js

api in backend express.js

```
const express = require("express");
const multer = require("multer");

const donationController = require("../controller/donationController");

const router = express.Router();

const multerStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callBack) {
    callBack(null, "");
  },
});

const uploadImage = multer({ storage: multerStorage }).single("recevierImages");

router.post("/create", uploadImage, donationController.createDonation);
router.patch("/update", donationController.updateDonation);

module.exports = router;
```

> donationController.js

```
const createDonation = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.file.buffer);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
}

module.exports = {
  createDonation,
};
```

In donationController.js req.file.buffer is undefined

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69921812/multer-file-buffer-missing

Comment: Thank you Traynor, i am able to get buffer in express API

Answer (score 0):

you need to set attribute in your form **enctype="multipart/form-data"** and because you send buffer from your react app you better to use memoryStorage instead of diskStorage and .single() you need pass your field name.

in frontend

```
<Form.Item> enctype="multipart/form-data" name="donationImage" label="Upload Image" action="#" method="post">
  <input type="file" onChange={(e) => handleUpload(e)} name="myfile" />
</Form.Item>
```

and your express app

```
const donationController = require("../controller/donationController");
const router = express.Router();
const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const uploadImage = multer({ storage: storage });

router.post("/create",uploadImage.single("myfile"),donationController.createDonatio);
```